# Rails Hash/Array Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationships

So I have three models going on.

Model 1: Questions with a has_many relationships to Answers

Model 2: Answers (belongs_to Questions)

Model 3: A User

Here's my conundrum. Upon answering my questions, I would like my user to have a property that indicates their answers for every question, so I can compare them later. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `user_id` field to answers and set its value to match the id of the user that provided the answers. This way you can later query the answers that belong to a/the particular user.

Comment: Thanks for that! What if I didn't have a answer and just a question with a integer value that would represent an answer?

Comment: Assuming you want to get answers from multiple users, you still need the answer model (2) so you still can add the `user_id` to this model. If you really want the answer from a single user, add `user_id` to the question model (1).